# Weird activity with Google Big Query

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am exporting a data frame to a Google Query Table.  My data frame looks fine; confirmed by exporting to a CSV.  All field names in the data frame match what is in the table in Google Big Query.  My export code looks like this.

```
final_df.to_gbq('database_name.table_name', 'project_ID', chunksize=None, verbose=None, reauth=False, if_exists='replace', private_key=None, auth_local_webserver=False, table_schema=None)
```

It seems like the data is exported and the process runs for about 21 seconds.

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
1it [00:21, 21.06s/it]
```

I get no error message whatsoever.  However, when I run a select * on the table, I get no records returned.  It's so weird because Python tells me everything ran, but there is absolutely nothing in the table!!  How can I validate what is actually going on here, because what it's not what I think it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had problems earlier with the chained version of to_gbq function, when importing pandas_gbg as a module I got it to work:

import pandas_gbq
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(final_df, 'database_name.table_name', 'project_id', if_exists='replace')

not sure it will solve your problem but worth a try!

Comment: It was weird that I received no errors, but now it works.  Thanks!